# How to customize jquery-visualize?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery-visualize in order to generate a chart. The problem is that I can not define a color for each column in part. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You call them in an array like this:

```
$('table').visualize({
    type: 'bar', 
    height: '250px', 
    width: '630px', 
    colors: [ '#3366cc','#dc3912','#ff9900','#109618','#990099','#824123' ]
});
```